# Seclective parse BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to parse data from Drug website. This parse need to be selective and this is the code I used:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_details(url):
    print('details:', url)

    # get subpage
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text ,"lxml")

    # get data on subpabe
    dts = soup.findAll('dt')
    dds = soup.findAll('dd')

    # display details
    for dt, dd in zip(dts, dds):
        print(dt.text)
        print(dd.text)
        print('---')

    print('---------------------------')

def drug_data():
    url = 'https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/'

    while url:
        print(url)
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text ,"lxml")

        # get links to subpages
        links = soup.select('strong a')
        for link in links:
            # exeecute function to get subpage
            get_details('https://www.drugbank.ca' + link['href'])

        # next page url
        url = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'page-link', 'rel': 'next'})
        print(url)
        if url:
            url = 'https://www.drugbank.ca' + url[0].get('href')
        else:
            break

drug_data()
```

This is working well. But what about more deep and selective parse ? Let's say for this drug : https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB01614  When I parse "PATENT" using my code, it will concatenate all the information of "PATENT" ( represented as a sub-table) in one paragraph.

Ideally, if I can parse PATENTS but extract only "patent number" , "approved" and the country represented by a Flag ! in separate columns !
Some help ?

Here is the patent screen shot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsmCr.jpg)

Comment: By `patent number`, do you mean Accession Number? And by `approved` do you mean Groups? Also I can't see a flag anywhere.

Comment: It is in the bottom of the page

Comment: I see it now, the patents are not available for the link you provided.

Comment: https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB00639

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for `Accession Number` and `Groups`, you can do the following:

```
def get_details(url):
    print('Details:', url)

    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    accession_dt = soup.find('dt', text='Accession Number')
    accession_number = accession_dt.nextSibling.string
    groups_dt = soup.find('dt', text='Groups')
    groups = groups_dt.nextSibling.string

    print('Accession number: ' + accession_number)
    print('Groups: ' + groups)
```

For the url that you provided, the output is as follows:

```
>>> get_details('https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB01614')
Details: https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB01614
Accession number: DB01614
Groups: Approved, Vet Approved
```

---

If you want to generalize this, you can define a function that returns the text of the key that you pass as a parameter:

```
def get_value(soup, key):
    key_dt = soup.find('dt', text=key)
    return key_dt.nextSibling.string
```

To use this function, you can do this:

```
def get_details(url):
    print('Details:', url)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    accession_number = get_value(soup, 'Accession Number')
    groups = get_value(soup, 'Groups')
    print('Accession number: ' + accession_number)
    print('Groups: ' + groups)
```

Which gives the same output as shown above.

---

**EDIT: The answer to the question**

This will give directly what you wanted.

```
def get_details(url):
    print('Details:', url)

    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    patents = soup.find('dt', text='Patents').nextSibling
    if patents.string == 'Not Available':
        print('Patent: Not Available')
    else:
        for i, row in enumerate(patents.find('tbody').findAll('tr')):
            print('\nPatent entry %d:' % (i+1))
            patent_number = row.find('a').text
            patent_approved = row.findAll('td')[2].text
            patent_country = row.find('img')['alt']
            print('Patent number: ' + patent_number)
            print('Approved: ' + patent_approved)
            print('Country: ' + patent_country)
```

For the drug: https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB00639, the output is

```
Details: https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB00639

Patent entry 1:
Patent number: US5266329
Approved: 1993-11-30
Country: Us

Patent entry 2:
Patent number: US5993856
Approved: 1997-11-17
Country: Us
```

Comment: After the comment, I can see that this is not what you were looking for. But i'll keep this here as it is similar to what you wanted.

Comment: I've edited the answer and added the solution at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I m running the whole code right now and trying to add patent/approved/country columns in the final csv output